# Sequence of evaluation in the following non blocking code?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, system-verilog, asic

I have the following verilog code that I came across and trying to find the sequence of evaluation. What value does 'A' have at the end of a cycle and after 5 cycles, when the value of A is 'x' at cycle 0.

```
always @ (posedge clk)

A <= 1;
A <= A+1;
B <= A+1;
```

I understand that the evaluation of RHS is done on the posedge and the assignment happens at the end of the cycle. What value would A have after the assignment? Is it '1' or 'X'?

Also does adding the delay to the statements act as blocking for the following code?

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
#5 A<=1;
#5 A<=A+1;
B <=A+1;
end
```

Comment: I edited your post to format the code blocks. Please check for correctness. I did remove two leading slashes on the lines starting with `#`, since I assume you put them there to avoid formatting the lines as headings, right?

Comment: You are missing th `begin`/`end` block. Is it intended?

Comment: Thanks @Justin for the edit, This interface is new to me. Missing `begin/end` block was intentional @Eugene Sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is a `begin/end` around the three assigment statements. Otherwise the code is legal.

Because you are using non-blocking assignments (NBA) in your first example, `A` has the *old* value throughout the current time step. If you have 2 NBA to the same variable in the same timestep, the last one wins. So at the end of the timestep, `A` has the value `A+1`. After 5 cycles, it has the value `A+5` Since you didn't specify how `A` gets initialized, that's the best answer you can get. Also realize that your code (enclosed by a single `begin/end`)is equivalent to

```
always @ (posedge clk) A <= 1;
always @ (posedge clk) A <= A+1;
always @ (posedge clk) B <= A+1;
```

In the second example when executing `A<=A+1`, `A` already is already updated to its new value, 1, so `A` would be 2. Note that blocking delays would not be allowed in synthesizable code.

Comment: Agree, So the value to B gets assigned before the blocking delay statements are evaluated or after ?

Comment: There is no blocking delay between the second assignment to `A` and the assignment to `B`. You should try experimenting.